# How to query a delimited value list generated by function (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've got a module sub getFileList() that generates a value list that outputs the following:

```
10347 C;12-0605 TPX;12-0713 tpx;13-0915 tpx;13-4304 tpx;1345 c;1375 c;14-4201 tpx;
```

I wanted to build a query against this function.

In the SQL view I've got the following:

```
SELECT getFileList("\\wwdata\dev\_commons\color","*.jpg") as colors;
```

Right now the value list is all in one record.

```
Colors
10347 C;12-0605 TPX;12-0713 tpx; etc....
```

What function/command is available to make this into a list with each delimited item as a record.

Desired output.

```
Colors
10347 C
12-0605 TPX
12-0713 tpx
13-0915 tpx
13-4304 tpx
1345 c
etc....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: VBA has a *Split()* function for just this purpose, with the same signature as the VB.NET eponymous function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I assumed the sql would then look like : SELECT split(getFileList("\\wwdata\dev\_commons\color","*.jpg"),";") as colors;
 but I'm getting an undefined function "split" error.

Comment: Does it have to be a select statement? If so how are you calling this Query? Through VBA or double clicking the Query in the navigation?

Comment: This was being called in Access Query: SQL view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, personally, I'd prefer to parse that delimited string in to an actual table in Access, and then run whatever query you want off that.

The following assumes there's already an empty table called "tblColors" and a short text field in that table called "Colors", which will be the target for parsing each ";" delimited item in your string into its own record in that table:

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim myDelimStr As String
    Dim arrayToParse As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arrayMsg As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblColors")

    myDelimStr = "10347 C;12-0605 TPX;12-0713 tpx;13-0915 tpx;13-4304 tpx;1345 c;1375 c;14-4201 tpx;"

    arrayToParse = Split(myDelimStr, ";", -1, vbTextCompare)

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayToParse) - 1

        rs.AddNew
        rs("Colors").Value = arrayToParse(i)
        rs.Update
        arrayMsg = arrayMsg & arrayToParse(i) & vbCrLf

    Next i

    Debug.Print "The array has parsed the following to the Colors table: " & vbCrLf & arrayMsg

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

You'll probably want to set `myDelimStr` to `myDelimStr = getFileList("\\wwdata\dev\_commons\color","*.jpg")` too.

Comment: this is pretty much what I was trying to do. Build a table from the function. Thanks.